# Lista nao atribuida

Tags: r

Pretendo associar uma coluna de IDs para o respetivo nome. Ou seja, em cada linha de IDS tenho uma lista de genes. e a essa lista de genes quero associar o nome dos genes. 
Aqui esta o meu codigo:

```
geneIDS<- Cas1_go_BP2[, 6] #vector with the IDS

allgencNames<- vector(length = length(geneIDS))

for (i in 1:length(geneIDS)) {
  geneIDS_split<- unlist(strsplit(as.character(geneIDS[i]), ","))
  geneIDs_split2<-as.character(gsub(" ", "", as.character(geneIDS_split))) 
  geneNames_split2<-DEG_ID[match(geneIDs_split2, DEG_ID[,2]), 1]
  geneNames<- paste(geneNames_split2, collapse = ",")
  allgencNames[i]<- geneNames
}


all_go_BP<- cbind(Cas1_go_BP, geneNames)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa, mas está com cara de ser um problema que se resolva com a função `merge()`.

Comment: Bom dia, ja resolvi o problema, obrigada

Comment: @Sofia então responda você mesma com a solução e feche a pergunta!